# Possessive for name with implied plural

Tags: possessives

As a rule (unless this really is a case-by-case basis) what's the correct possessive form for a company name that is pluralized for the singular?

For example, the company "JetBrains" uses the plural "Brains" for the singular company entity, "JetBrains."

Should it be "JetBrain's product line," "JetBrains' product line" or something else besides?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That other question is very similar but I see this one as the general case ( (provided we delete 'company' in the title). With that small change it would be more useful in future. I vote we keep this one open with the new title.

Comment: I went ahead and modified the title, and I'll allow you guys to decide if this is unique. I honestly don't know if it is.