# How to write the possessive of a proper noun that ends in a plural noun?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, names, proper-nouns

Say we have a hotel named the Springfield Arms. The name itself is singular, since it refers to an individual hotel, but it ends with the pluralized noun “Arms”.

What is the correct way to write the possessive of this hotel’s name? Do you treat it as a singular noun overall ("the Springfield Arms’s address"), or as a plural noun ("the Springfield Arms’ address")?

I know the issue can be sidestepped by rephrasing, such as with “the address of the Springfield Arms hotel”, but I’m still curious what the actual answer is.

---

I found a couple similar questions ([Possessive for name with implied plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266553/possessive-for-name-with-implied-plural), [Possessive Form of a Proper Noun Ending in a Plural Noun Ending in "s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89705/possessive-form-of-a-proper-noun-ending-in-a-plural-noun-ending-in-s)), but the former was closed without answers and points to the latter, whereas the latter’s answers vary widely and I can’t discern any clear rule or convention. The latter is also closed pointing the a *third* question (see below), which doesn’t address mine.

To clarify, this question is not a duplicate of [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe) — the two questions are about entirely different things. That question asks which *singular names* like “James” and “Aeneas” are subject to exceptions to rules about possessive forms with regard to sibilants; my question asks whether a *compound singular name ending in a plural noun* should be treated as singular or plural overall. That is not the same at all (for instance, regardless of the possessive rule used, there is no question that “James” is a strictly singular name).

Comment: A hint: James is a singular name. The hat belonging to James is James’ hat.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but “Arms” is a plural noun, not just a singular name that happens to end in -s, so I want to know whether that makes a difference.

Comment: Google Books suggests Sergeant-at-Arms's is common, but struggling to find examples with a pub. Some people would say you shouldn't use apostrophe-S with an inanimate object, but I think that's a little too pedantic.

Comment: I believe it is the final "s" that matters. Though "James' hat" is often pronounced like "James's hat".

Comment: Personally I prefer using apostrophe-s for any singular nouns and names that end in “-s”, regardless of what they are or how they’re used. (I know some style guides have special rules for things like certain classical names, or whether the final “-s” is silent, or whether the next word starts with an “s-”, etc., but I personally think that’s all overly pedantic, so I ignore it.)

Comment: The first question to ask yourself is: how would I say it aloud?

Comment: Personally, I’d say “arms-es”, and “Arms’s” seems the most logical as the full name is a singular noun. But I’m skeptical of relying on people’s subjective speech patterns, including my own (for instance, “I and my friends” seems logical to me, even though I know it’s incorrect).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe) // “Arms” is a plural-form noun treated as singular (the Springfield Arms is about a mile further on). The duplicate says that form follows pronunciation, and I doubt whether two syllables (requiring 's) would be used by many. The situation is different with _the Jones' / Jones's house_, both variants being used.

Comment: That question doesn’t answer mine. That question is about singular names that happen to end in “-s”, like “James”, whereas mine is about a compound singular name that ends with a _plural noun_, even if it’s treated as singular. The end result may be similar, but the substance – and confusion caused – is different enough that it matters, IMO, which is why people keep asking this question (like the ones I linked in the OP). Nevertheless, @tinfoil-hat below posted what I think is the right answer, by showing that it’s ultimately up to stylistic choice rather than covered by any hard rule.

Comment: 'James' and 'Springfield Arms' are alike nouns plural in form but taking singular agreement. The fact that one is an open compound makes no difference; the most widely accepted rule for forming the Saxon genitive is pronunciation dependent. Hence James' hat or James's hat, depending on how the writer chooses to pronounce it, but the Springfield Arms’ address. // The duplicate even has the example Callaway Gardens' former curator.

Comment: While this question is answered by a paragraph in the [linked question's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081) second answer, I think this one should be kept open since that other answer only happened because Sven Yargs is so thorough. Other people who wish to write an answer to this question might not want to answer the other question about singular names like "James".

Comment: How about Greek names? _Parmenides's, Socrates's, Heraclitus's_?

Comment: The material is duplicated, and the thorough answer, which is not **too** broad in scope, should alone be kept. 'That question doesn’t answer mine' is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363229/adding-a-possessive-to-a-singular-noun-phrase-that-ends-in-a-plural-noun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is between you and your style guide of choice.

Mine is *The Chicago Manual of Style*, so I would go with the rule for “a plural form ending in *s* . . . even though the entity is singular”: ***the Springfield Arms’ address***.

> **7.20: Possessive of nouns plural in form, singular in meaning**
>
> When the singular form of a noun ending in s is the same as the plural
> (i.e., the plural is uninflected), the possessives of both are formed
> by the addition of an apostrophe only. If ambiguity threatens, use
> *of* to avoid the possessive.
>  <sub>politics’ true meaning</sub>
>  <sub>economics’ forerunners</sub>
>  <sub>this
> species’ first record (*or, better,* the first record of this
> species)</sub>
>
> The same rule applies when the name of a place or an organization or a
> publication (or the last element in the name) is a plural form ending
> in *s*, such as *the United States*, even though the entity is
> singular.
>  <sub>the United States’ role in international
> law</sub>
>  <sub>Highland Hills’ late mayor</sub>
>  <sub>Callaway
> Gardens’ former curator</sub>
>  <sub>the National Academy of
> Sciences’ new policy</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of
> Style*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) (login required)</sub>

Comment: Ah, I was wondering whether any style guides covered it. I personally differ from the _CMoS_ on some of these, but seeing that the matter really is just a matter of stylistic choice rather than any hard & fast rule answers my question. Thanks.